# Возможно ли вместо тел. проверить поле email c помощью плагина inputmask?

Tags: javascript

Есть всплывающая форма, где предлагается оставить email для связи.

Но необходимо сделать минимальную проверку для защиты от всяких скриптов, а также на правильность заполнения хотя бы '@' и минимального кол-ва символов.

С формой ввода тел. у меня получилось так:

```html
 $("input[type='text']").inputmask({"mask": "+7 (999) 999-9999"});
 
 
 /*$("form").on("submit", function() {
  var phone = $("input[type='text']").val();
  var regex = /\+7 \(\d{3}\) \d{3}\-\d{4}/;
  if (phone.search(regex) == -1) {
   alert("Укажите правильный номер телефона!");
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 });
```

Для email пробовал написать такое рег.

```html
    var email = $("input[type='text']").val();
 var regex =  $.trim(oEmailText.val()).replace(/^[\s_@.]+$/g, '');
```

Comment: Защита от скриптов делается не запретами, а экранированием

Comment: Кроме того, никогда не забывайте, что любую проверку в браузере можно обойти